# How to populate many textboxes from a sql query automatically?

Tags: asp.net, sql, textbox

This might be a silly question. But I have a lot of textboxes in an in asp.net form I need to populate with data from a sql query.

If the query column names and textbox names are all the same, is it possible to populate the textboxes from the query data automatically? Maybe using loop? There are too many fields so I think it is stupid to populate each field individually using something like:

```
textboxX.text = data.getValue(0).ToString(); 
textboxY.text = data.getValue(1).ToString(); 
...
```

I am thinking there must be a simpler way to populate all of the textboxes. Can anyone please help me to do this? A simple example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using something like MVC or MVVM then it would be in a manner of speaking.   You could tie your view page to a model that has properties corresponding to the fields.  Then in your view page you would bind the model properties to the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I am just using asp.net without MVC. I just have relized after I have created my project and it is too late to change it to MVC. Is there any other way without mvc?

Comment: Have never tried this, but maybe with JSON.   You could create a class that holds all of the parameters in your page with the names exactly the same as the form fields (remember to use clienidmode = static in the aspx page) then with ajax call that as a JSON object and iterate through using a loop in jquery that links the values to the input fields by name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't work with MVC/MVVM/knockout then the best thing you could do is to loop your form's controls and assign them some values from your list. For this purpose it's simplier if your controls are named like Ctrl1, Ctrl2, etc - it's just to simplify the looping/assignment